# <Original/genuine/authentic> painting

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

I know the words "genuine" and "original" and "authentic":

> - Authentic --> real or true
> - Genuine--> not fake
> - Original--> the first copy of something

But I have no idea how they can be used regarding copy/not copy version of a painting in natural English.

> For instance, let's suppose a person pretends that they have the Monna Lisa drawn by Leonardo Da Vinci at hand, and they want to sell it (assumption).
>   You as a specialist want to prove that it is genuine/original/authentic or not, what would you say after making sure that the painting is not the one that Davinci drew it?

1-1- The painting is (not) original! 
1-2- The painting is (not) genuine!
1-3- The painting is (not) authentic!

> Meanwhile, if Leonardo da Vinci had painted a copy of a painting by Raphael, and we could prove that he painted it, it would be:

2-1- Original
2-2- Genuine
2-3- Authentic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first scenario, **authentic** would be the most common word to use for a painting that has been proven to truly be by the painter it is supposed to be by. It sounds the most scientific, and matches the name of the process of proving if a painting/document is "true" - "**authentication**"

---

However, saying "This is a genuine Da Vinci" also does not sound weird, but has a slightly more colloquial/emotional tone.

"This painting is genuine" without context, could also mean that whoever is looking at the painting believes the painter truly felt emotions while painting it. AKA the painter is not a sell-out. Authentic can also be used in this sense, but for things able to be authenticated that meaning is usually not used.

As you say "original" typically refers to the first of something, that is later extensively copied for example. Therefore if say someone thought they bought a novelty U.S. Constitution in Washington D.C. but found out it was the real constitution, they would say "This is **the** original"

---

As for the second scenario... That one is harder. The word combination that comes to mind would be "a genuine forgery" or "authentic fake" or something. This is clearly a oxymoron, so you would then have to explain, "it is fake Raphael painting really painted Da Vinci." If you didn't care to talk about the fact that it was a copy of Raphael, then either "an authentic Da Vinci" or "a genuine Da Vinci" would be appropriate. But you wouldn't call it outright genuine, or authentic. That would ask the question "authentically what?", "genuinely what?"

Comment: Thank you @katatahito. +1 for the informative post. But how about my second scenario?

Comment: edited to include info for last scenario